# jquery validate check at least one checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have something like this:

```
<form>
<input name='roles' type='checkbox' value='1' />
<input name='roles' type='checkbox' value='2' />
<input name='roles' type='checkbox' value='3' />
<input name='roles' type='checkbox' value='4' />
<input name='roles' type='checkbox' value='5' />
<input type='submit' value='submit' />
<form>
```

I would like to validate that at least one checkbox (roles) should be checked, is it possible with jquery.validate ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The validate plugin will only validate the current/focused element.Therefore you will need to add a custom rule to the validator to validate all the checkboxes. Similar to the answer above.

```
$.validator.addMethod("roles", function(value, elem, param) {
   return $(".roles:checkbox:checked").length > 0;
},"You must select at least one!");
```

And on the element:

```
<input class='{roles: true}' name='roles' type='checkbox' value='1' />
```

In addition, you will likely find the error message display, not quite sufficient. 
Only 1 checkbox is highlighted and only 1 message displayed. If you click another separate checkbox, which then returns a valid for the second checkbox, the original one is still marked as invalid, and the error message is still displayed, despite the form being valid.
I have always resorted to just displaying and hiding the errors myself in this case.The validator then only takes care of not submitting the form.

The other option you have is to write a function that will change the value of a hidden input to be "valid" on the click of a checkbox and then attach the validation rule to the hidden element. This will only validate in the onSubmit event though, but will display and hide messages at the appropriate times. Those are about the only options that you can use with the validate plugin.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This answer must be outdated or something.  You can simply use the `required` rule as long as all checkboxes in the group have the same `name`.  See [the real correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4120320/594235) and this demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/AsuyC/

Comment: What's up with that class name? `{roles: true}` is in no way valid for a class...

Comment: stick `required` attribute and `title="Choose a foo"` with the input element

Answer (score 113):

Example from [https://github.com/ffmike/jquery-validate](https://github.com/ffmike/jquery-validate/tree/master/demo)

```
 <label for="spam_email">
     <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="spam_email" value="email" name="spam[]" validate="required:true, minlength:2" /> Spam via E-Mail </label>
 <label for="spam_phone">
     <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="spam_phone" value="phone" name="spam[]" /> Spam via Phone </label>
 <label for="spam_mail">
     <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="spam_mail" value="mail" name="spam[]" /> Spam via Mail </label>
 <label for="spam[]" class="error">Please select at least two types of spam.</label>
```

The same without field "validate" in tags only using javascript:

```
$("#testform").validate({ 
    rules: { 
            "spam[]": { 
                    required: true, 
                    minlength: 1 
            } 
    }, 
    messages: { 
            "spam[]": "Please select at least two types of spam."
    } 
});
```

And if you need different names for inputs, you can use somethig like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="spam" id="spam"/>
<label for="spam_phone">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="spam_phone" value="phone" name="spam_phone" /> Spam via Phone</label>
<label for="spam_mail">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="spam_mail" value="mail" name="spam_mail" /> Spam via Mail </label>
```

Javascript:

```
 $("#testform").validate({ 
    rules: { 
        spam: { 
            required: function (element) {
                var boxes = $('.checkbox');
                if (boxes.filter(':checked').length == 0) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            },
            minlength: 1 
        } 
    }, 
    messages: { 
            spam: "Please select at least two types of spam."
    } 
});
```

I have added hidden input before inputs and setting it to "required" if there is no selected checkboxes

Comment: Just wanted to mention that if you are adding the validation rules via the DOM `<input type='checkbox' name='group' required minlength='2' ...>`, the first checkbox of the group must contain the validation rules. If you do it on following checkboxes, the validation will not get triggered.

Comment: I can't get validation to fire for the hidden checkbox: https://jsfiddle.net/rzyhhuz0/1/

Comment: It will not validate hidden fields. You need to add ignore to settings; so right above rules add: `ignore: $('#spam'), `

Comment: @sir umm, wait, the label's `for` is bound to the input's `id`, right?

Answer (score 18):

Mmm first your id attributes must be unique, your code is likely to be

```
<form>
<input class='roles' name='roles' type='checkbox' value='1' />
<input class='roles' name='roles' type='checkbox' value='2' />
<input class='roles' name='roles' type='checkbox' value='3' />
<input class='roles' name='roles' type='checkbox' value='4' />
<input class='roles' name='roles' type='checkbox' value='5' />
<input type='submit' value='submit' />
</form>
```

For your problem :

```
if($('.roles:checkbox:checked').length == 0)
  // no checkbox checked, do something...
else
  // at least one checkbox checked...
```

BUT, remember that a JavaScript form validation is only indicative, all validations MUST be done server-side.

Comment: actually I don't care about the ids I need the same name for them so I would a get the result at the server side in this form "1,2,5", I'm using jquery.validate for client-side validation, and would like to make it validate my form in this scenario

Comment: Although it doesn't have anything to do with the jquery validate plugin, this is the best and simplest answer.

Comment: Thx alot brother, God Bless YOU :D

Answer (score 7):

```
$("#idform").validate({
    rules: {            
        'roles': {
            required: true,
        },
    },
    messages: {            
        'roles': {
            required: "One Option please",
        },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

This is how I have dealt with it in the past:

```
$().ready(function() {                                                      
    $("#contact").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // see if selectone is even being used
            var boxes = $('.selectone:checkbox');
            if(boxes.length > 0) {
                if( $('.selectone:checkbox:checked').length < 1) {
                    alert('Please select at least one checkbox');
                    boxes[0].focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            form.submit();
        }
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 3):

[sir_neanderthal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500157/sir-neanderthal) has already posted a nice answer.

I just want to point out that if you would like to use different names for your inputs you can also use (or just copy the method) **[require_from_group method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method)** from official jQuery Validation **additional-methods.js** ([link to CDN for version 1.13.1](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/additional-methods.js)).

Answer (score 2):

It's highly probable that you want to have a text next to the checkbox. In that case, you can put the checkbox inside a label like I do below:

```
<label style="width: 150px;"><input type="checkbox" name="damageTypeItems" value="72" aria-required="true" class="error"> All Over</label>
<label style="width: 150px;"><input type="checkbox" name="damageTypeItems" value="73" aria-required="true" class="error"> All Over X2</label>
```

The problem is that when the error message is displayed, it's going to be inserted after the checkbox but before the text, making it unreadable. In order to fix that, I changed the error placement function:

```
if (element.is(":checkbox")) {
    error.insertAfter(element.parent().parent());
}
else {
    error.insertAfter(element);
}
```

It depends on your layout but what I did is to have a special error placement for checkbox controls. I get the parent of the checkbox, which is a label, and then I get the parent of it, which is a div in my case. This way, the error is placed below the list of checkbox controls.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the `input-name[]` is in inverted commas in the ruleset.  Took me hours to figure that part out.

```
$('#testform').validate({
  rules : {
    "name[]": { required: true, minlength: 1 }
  }
});
```

read more here...
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Valid...ets.2C_dots.29

Comment: "_inverted commas_"??  You mean quotation marks?  Since the OP's `name` is simply `roles` (no special characters), this has nothing to do with anything here.

Answer (score -1):

```
 if ($('input:checkbox').filter(':checked').length < 1){
        alert("Check at least one!");
 return false;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please add a brief explanation of how it works and why it's a good solution to the problem to help OP and future visitors.