# jquery validate addMethod not working

Tags: jquery, validation

The following code produces an error if the conditions are met, but doesn't remove the error class if corrected. Basically if you check "#MKDPT" and none in the array are checked, show the error. If any in the array are checked, remove or don't show the error.

```
$.validator.addMethod('MKDPTOnly', function(value, element) {
            var ckd = ['AMX1N','BMFNP','BMFNB','CFE1N','CBEXR','CBT1','CBTQL','CME1','CMEQL','CMX1','DCMX1','DMERT','DMEDL','ERX1N','ERXXN','EXC1N','EXD1N','EXR1N','EXI1N','IPE1','KCB1','LME1','DLME1','MPL1','NDQ1N','NDQL2','CEC1','ICEFI','NYM1','DNYM1','NYMQL','NYS1N','NYSLM','PNK1P','PNK2N','SMX1', 'CNC1N','CNS1N','MTL1N','MTL2N','MTN1N','MTN2N','WEA1'];
            var otherChecked = $('#' + ckd.join(',#')).filter(':checked').length > 0;
             return !$(element).is(':checked') || otherChecked;
        }, 'Market Depth ($20) is only required with a Real Time Exchange.');
```

*************EDIT**********************
now i can remove class by unchecking #MKDPT, but clicking any of the var checkboxes does not clear error

```
$.validator.addMethod(
            'MKDPTOnly',
            function(value, element){
                var ckd = ['AMX1N','BMFNP','BMFNB','CFE1N','CBEXR','CBT1','CBTQL','CME1','CMEQL','CMX1','DCMX1','DMERT','DMEDL','ERX1N','ERXXN','EXC1N','EXD1N','EXR1N','EXI1N','IPE1','KCB1','LME1','DLME1','MPL1','NDQ1N','NDQL2','CEC1','ICEFI','NYM1','DNYM1','NYMQL','NYS1N','NYSLM','PNK1P','PNK2N','SMX1', 'CNC1N','CNS1N','MTL1N','MTL2N','MTN1N','MTN2N','WEA1'];
                if ($('#MKDPT').is(':checked') && $('#' + ckd.join(',#')).filter(':checked').length == 0) {
                    return false;
                } else { return true; }
            },'Market Depth ($20) is only required with a Real Time Exchange.');
```

Comment: I would set the value of a hidden element based on whether a checkbox has been checked or not. Then attach the appropriate validation rule to the hidden element. The multiple checkbox & error message is a known issue with the validator.

Comment: See the following question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035634/jquery-validate-check-at-least-one-checkbox/3050665#3050665]  with very similar problem

Comment: @menzies - very interesting. something like <input type="hidden" id="foo" value=""> then if the checkboxes have length give "foo" a value. If it has a value, validate it?

Comment: Yeah - something like that. The only issue with this is that hidden elements only validate in the onsubmit event. So you would not get the error appearing/disappearing until then.

Comment: well that's no good. using a form "wizard" to break it down into steps - I guess I could make it a click function for the "next" and "prev" buttons. fun.

Comment: you can manually validate elements and then trigger the call with the click of the next button. I have done this for wizards in the past. Put all the elements in a div and pass that in as the element to be validated.see the following docs [http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/element#element]

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to solve this possibly a brutish way.

I added an ID to the span that holds the error element "#MDC"
that allowed me to target the "p.error" via it's parent ID "#MDC"

I then added a class to all of the checkboxes in the var ckd ".mdh"

In my JS file I have the $.validator.addMethod above that if "#MKDPT" is checked and none of the var ckd are display a p.error and add class '.error' to the "#MKDPT" checkbox The problem I was having was removing the p.error and switching the "#MKDPT" from ".error" to ".valid" so you can go on with the form.

I solved it thusly:

```
$(".mdh").live('click', function(){
            if ($(".ex").is(":checked")) {                           
                $("#MKDPT").removeClass("error").addClass("valid");
                $("#MDC > p.error").hide();
                $("#MDerror").hide();
            } else {
                $("#MKDPT").removeClass("valid").addClass("error");
                $("#MDC > p.error").show();
                $("#MDerror").show();
            }
        });
```

so now if "#MDKPT" has class ".error" and the p.error is shown, when you click on the checkbox with a class of ".mdh" it removes the class ".error" adds class ".valid" hides the "p.error" and allows you to continue. if you uncheck or have none of the ".mdh" checked, it displays error, adds class ".error" and stops progression through form. works well, although I'm sure someone smarter has a better solution.