# minimum one required for checkboxes with same name

Tags: html, checkbox

I have html code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="true[1][]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="true[1][]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="true[1][]" value="3">

...

<input type="checkbox" name="true[2][]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="true[2][]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="true[2][]" value="3">

...
```

How can I set **minimum one required** for checkboxes **with same name**? **For example**: minimum one required for group true[1][], minumum one required for group true[2][].

It should be **without JS** =) Only **HTML**.

Comment: I think this post answers the same questions , phrased differently, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218494/using-the-html5-required-attribute-for-a-group-of-checkboxes . Hope it helps.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035634/jquery-validate-check-at-least-one-checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035634/jquery-validate-check-at-least-one-checkbox) see this @Bohdan

Comment: @Prashant123 I wrote: It should be without JS...

Comment: can you check more than one? if not use radio buttons

Comment: Without using JS this would be easiest to achieve server side on POST. Are you using a server side language?