# How to validate that at least one checkbox is checked using the validate jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

Okey, the thing is i have a form that has to be validated, using the jquery validation plugin i've managed to validate everything but a question with checkboxes. So, here's my code:

```
<form id="myform" class="fs-form fs-form-full" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q3" data-info="This will help us know what kind of service you need">What's your priority for your new website?</label>
    <div id="span-display_box" class="fs-checkbox-group fs-checkbox-custom clearfix fs-anim-lower">
        <span><input class="priority" id="q3a" name="q3[]" type="checkbox" value="mobile"/><label for="q3a" class="checkbox-mobile">Mobile market</label></span>
        <span><input class="priority" id="q3b" name="q3[]" type="checkbox" value="conversion"/><label for="q3b" class="checkbox-conversion">Sell things</label></span>
        <span><input class="priority" id="q3c" name="q3[]" type="checkbox" value="social"/><label for="q3c" class="checkbox-social">Become famous</label></span>
    </div>
    <button class="fs-submit" type="submit" onclick="">Send answers</button>
</form>
```

So, using the jquery validation plugin how i can validate the question, so at least one of them is checked?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And your `JavaScript` ?

Comment: Hi Please refer **@menzies**  answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035634/jquery-validate-check-at-least-one-checkbox