# Input type Checkbox Validation using Jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

I need to validate form using Jquery, below is my sample code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="field_1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="field_2" />
```

In the above two field any one field is required,I know this would be achieve by using radio button,for some reason I am using checkbox,I am trying below validation code,but I validate both fields

```
 $('#myForm').validate({
    rules: {
        field_1: {
            required: true,
            number: true
        },
        field_2: {
            required: true,
            number: true
        }
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Validation plugin: validate check box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453036/jquery-validation-plugin-validate-check-box)

Comment: refer the example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453036/jquery-validation-plugin-validate-check-box

Comment: write custom validation, your code won't work, which is pure field validation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035634/jquery-validate-check-at-least-one-checkbox plz refer this

Comment: Do you need your fields name should be different as above like `field_1` & `field_2` or can able to change this to the same name as `field`?

Comment: It is not duplicate guys, please, take a close look at question, at least read once thoroughly

Comment: @aruna : Yes ,need different field name

Comment: @shibon : Thanks for your response , It should be helpfull

Comment: @lalabyte : Please read my question once again, In that your refer link there is multi select check box and validate select atleast one box,but my question is user should select only one check box not multiple

Comment: What absolutely valid reason(s) do you have for conflating the functions of checkbox and radio buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below output,

```js
$('#myForm').validate({
  rules: {},
  messages: {},
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo(element.parent("td").next("td"));
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
   if($(".chk:checkbox:checked").length == 1)
   form.submit();
    else
    alert("Please select only once checkbox value..!");
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form name="asada" id="myForm" action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="field_1" class='chk' />
  <input type="checkbox" name="field_2" class='chk' />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I am operating in submit handler, there I am checking for strict check only one checkbox should be selected, else form wont submit.

I hope this will help.