# jQuery.validator.addMethod is not being executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a simplified version of a page I've been working on; I got some basic validation working [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59939544/jquery-validator-is-not-working-for-checkbox-lists-when-using-css-class-to-valid) but I want to integrate with the jQuery validator to get inline error messages instead of just alert boxes.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>pick a box, its contents will help you on your way!</title>
        <script src="jQuery-1.4.4-min.js"></script>
        <script src="jQuery-validate.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="fred">
            <input class="Notes8" name="Notes8~1" id="Notes8~1" type="checkbox" value="Yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 1<br>
            <input class="Notes8" name="Notes8~2" id="Notes8~2" type="checkbox" value="Yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 2<br>
            <input class="Notes8" name="Notes8~3" id="Notes8~3" type="checkbox" value="Yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 3<br>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                jQuery(function($) {
                    function validateMultiple (selector, n, isExactlyN) {
                        const totChecked = $(selector).filter(':checked').length;
                        return !(isExactlyN ? totChecked == n : totChecked >= n);
                    }
                    jQuery.validator.addMethod('.Notes8',
                        function(value, element) {
                            return validateMultiple('.Notes8', 1);
                        },
                        'Please check at least one check box.');
                });
            </script>
            <button type="submit">SUBMIT!</button>
        </form>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Problem is, the `jQuery.validator.addMethod` call doesn't seem to be working; no validation takes place and if I put `alert("FRED");` inside the `function(value, element)` then nothing is displayed, indicating that the validator method never got wired up properly. Why is this? How can I get the validation function to execute when I submit the form? I see no JavaScript errors in the browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `validate` method: `$("#fred").validate();`. There was also issue with your validation code - I removed unecessary negation. Also you don't need dot in `name` paramater in [`addMethod`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>pick a box, its contents will help you on your way!</title>
    <script src="jQuery-1.4.4-min.js"></script>
    <script src="jQuery-validate.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="fred">
        <input class="Notes8" name="Notes8~1" id="Notes8~1" type="checkbox" value="Yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 1<br>
        <input class="Notes8" name="Notes8~2" id="Notes8~2" type="checkbox" value="Yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 2<br>
        <input class="Notes8" name="Notes8~3" id="Notes8~3" type="checkbox" value="Yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 3<br>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            jQuery(function ($) {
                function validateMultiple(selector, n, isExactlyN) {
                    var totChecked = $(selector).filter(':checked').length;
                    return (isExactlyN ? totChecked == n : totChecked >= n);
                }
                jQuery.validator.addMethod('Notes8',
                    function (value, element) {
                        return validateMultiple('.Notes8', 1);
                    },
                    'Please check at least one check box.');
            });
            $("#fred").validate();
        </script>
        <button type="submit">SUBMIT!</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's got me going in the right direction! So now I have the validation message coming up three times, once for each check box. Is there any way to have it appear only once?

Comment: Oh, I figured it out - I had to create a variable `notes8valid` and fake the validation passing if it's already been set to false.